# How can I print spaces in prolog

Tags: prolog

i need to print into stream using write(), but I can't figure out how to print 'blank' spaces.
For example i want to write

```
       10    3     
   5     3    6
```

write('    10    3') just writes 10 3 (delets the extra spaces), and I want to print leading spaces. Does anybody know how I can do this?

edit: I want to print a matrix of characters which contains some blank spaces and some numbers. The end goal of a program is that. But if I do

```
?- write(' '), write(' '), write('3')
3
true
```

and I want to achieve

```
   3
```

Comment: You should take a look at **format/2** which is quite difficult to use !

Answer (score 0):

Please edit your question with a complete program we can run, and the output you get, and the output you would like to get.

This seems to work for me on SWI-Prolog 7.6.4:

```
?- write('10 3'), nl, write('    10    3    '), write('7'), nl.
10 3
    10    3    7
true.
```

Comment: I edited the post so now it should be clear what I'm trying to do

Comment: Thank you. What Prolog implementation are you using?

Comment: I use SWI-Prolog (SWISH)

Comment: I see. This is a known bug in SWISH: https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/swish/issues/120 . If you want to do this kind of formatted printing, you will probably have to switch to a Prolog installed on your local machine.